# Regex to find css class in HTML markup

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to find all instances of a CSS class name in HTML markup. So far I have this, assuming `row` is the class name that I'm looking for:

```
class=\"[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\s]*row[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\s]*\"
```

It correctly matches all of the following:

```
class="foo_bar bar row test"
class="row"
class="hello foo bar  row"
class=" foo bar  row test "
```

And correctly doesn't match this:

```
class="hello"  row
```

Unfortunately it incorrectly matches these (false positives):

```
class="narrow"
class="rowdy"
```

What regex will find a specific CSS class name in HTML?

**Update**
There are lots of comments about how I shouldn't parse the DOM with regex. My use case is to do a 'find all' in a large project with thousands of HTML files to find where specific CSS classes are being used. I'm not operating inside of a browser or have access to a DOM.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you *have* to use regex as opposed to a DOM parser here? If you have to, I'd say adding `\b` (word boundary) before and after `row` should do it, though I didn't really think this through so might be better ways.

Comment: Try `class="(?:row|[^"]* row)(?![^" ])[^"]*"` if `_row_` is not allowed too. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/Xq4sT9/1

Comment: Also what about `"hello a-row"`?

Comment: Oh yeah a word boundary isn't enough because of dashes (at least).

Comment: You forgot that `class = "` (notice the spaces) is also a legit syntax. And that a text `class="row` is also a legit text. Stop using regex to parse DOM. Use what browsers already use. A [**DOMParser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). [Tony the Pony he comes...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383904)

Comment: @Jeto there's no access to a DOM. I'm doing a 'find all' in a big project with thousands of HTML files using a code editor (e.g. Atom, VSCode, Visual Studio, etc).

Comment: @revo I'm looking for a specific class (e.g. `row`), so `a-row` should not match.

Comment: @revo Your regex works. Please post an answer so I can accept it. Not sure how that works, but it works. :-)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't have access to a DOM. I'm searching through thousands of HTML files with a text editor.

Comment: It works because it only allows a space or a double quote around `row`. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make boundaries but `\b` isn't enough since it matches the position between `-` and `r` in `a-row` which is expected but not intended. To define this boundary to only allow spaces or the position right after or before `"` of class attribute, you will need to write a pattern with two branches:

```
class="(?:row|[^"]* row)(?![^" ])[^"]*"
```

The above could be shorten to (but not preferred):

```
class="(?:[^"]* )?row(?![^" ])[^"]*"
```

Shorter but the same as longer one (talking performance-wise):

```
class="(?:[^"]* )??row(?: [^"]*)?"
```

Regex breakdown:

- `class="` Match `class="` literally
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `row` Match `row`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^"]* row` Match `row` preceded by a space character
- `)` End of capturing group
- `(?![^" ])` The next immediate character should be space or `"`
- `[^"]*"` Match up to and including `"`

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Xq4sT9/1/)

Comment: This is great and has saved me lots of time cleaning up CSS/HTML in a large project.

Comment: Glad to hear. I just looked at the regex and realized it could be written shorter without affecting performance. So I added it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex

**(class\s?=\s?)\"([\d\w\s-]*)(\brow\b)([\d\w\s]*)\"**

Tested all the cases you mentioned

[https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8KUw4l/1)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty good. It fails this test though: `class="flex-mt90 foo bar  row"  row`, but I realize that  I didn't have it in my list of examples. https://regex101.com/r/jeos4r/2